# How to store entered values to variables and display them on screen after clicking submit button in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, variables, store

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Welcome"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Name"
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Email"
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/email"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/name"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/name" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Mobile No"
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="phone"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/mob"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/email"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/email" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Gender"
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView3" />

<RadioButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Male"
    android:id="@+id/radioButton"
    android:checked="false"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/mob"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/mob" />

<RadioButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Feamle"
    android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
    android:checked="false"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/mob"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/mob" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Are you Married"
    android:id="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/radioButton"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<Switch
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="No"
    android:id="@+id/switch1"
    android:checked="false"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/radioButton1"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/radioButton1" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Submit"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

I have done such screen on my android studio and I want to accept those values from user, store it in the variables and after clicking submit button, I want to display those entered value to the user on another screen.

Can you please tell me the way should I write the Java code for this?

Should I have to create a new class for defining and storing variables or I have to write code in MainActivity.java file only?

What are the different packages needed to perform this work? Please give me some example of Java code so I can understand it clearly. Please guide me.

Comment: You really need to be researching how to use Android and Java. There are loads of materials out there, I'd recommend following an Android tutorial series on Youtube

Answer (score 0):

You just have xml file. Lot more things to done.

Have a look http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui.html

Comment: I also have default Java code in Android Studio. Thats I am asking. I need help to write Java code of above described program.